# ko.mapping is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

im following this example http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/badZb/ . I just copy and paste the exact code into a sample application and it gave me this error : "ko.mapping is undefined" . Anyone know whats happening? My ko.observable and dependentObservable are working great, is just that ko.mapping is not working.

FYI : The knockout.js version is 2.0 and Jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As the mapping plugin is exactly that, a *plugin*, it is not included in the core library.

You need to include the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) separately. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping). Just make sure you include it after including the core Knockout library.

Comment: OMG. Just kill me. Thanks alot

Comment: No problem :) Easy to overlook the obvious sometimes!

Comment: the problem i think is that there is a mapping walkthrough on knockout's primary site leading you to believe that it's baked in.